# Multiple express apps share same domain in different directories

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, directory

I have four node applications built using the express framework. I have one domain name `expressapps.com`, and I would like each of the three apps to run within different subdirectories. I would like the fourth app to run on the home page (and possibly delegate the other apps).

- expressapps.com
- expressapps.com/app-one
- expressapps.com/app-two
- expressapps.com/app-three

I want all of the apps to be able to be detached from the domain name and moved to a different one, not dependent on each other in any way, not to share cookies or session data. I would also like for the apps, on a node level to be running in different processes from each other. I'm guessing that the apps would all have to be on the same server, but is it possible to have them on different?

The reason I would do this rather then use sub-domians is because of `ssl`, I only want to have to purchase one certificate.

Is this possible? Is there anything out there to aid this configuration?

Comment: why not just use a separate port for each one?

Comment: @chovy not really user friendly, but would work.

Comment: using ports would work w/o doing anything special. Is this just for development, or are you trying to serve 3 different production apps on the same domain? Just curious why you don't have different domains.

Comment: SSL how many times, do I have to wright it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like [`haproxy`](http://haproxy) which will allow you to have different apps live on different servers but all be under one domain and forwarded to another.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way would be with subdomains, not ports.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to do sub-domains:

```
http://expressapps.com
http://app-one.expressapps.com
http://app-two.expressapps.com
http://app-three.expressapps.com
```

The benefit here, being that you can host each app in a separate place, maybe even on different servers or with different hosting services, and then just change your DNS settings to point those sub-domains to the appropriate places. Make sense?

Comment: Hey, fancy seeing you here went to your node talk. Yeah, but then I have to purchase a ssl certificate for each domain name. I am aware I can use subdomains, I'm just wondering if there are any tricks to getting directories working.

Comment: Hey hey! That's awesome, hope you enjoyed the talk, did my best to make it fun. Yes, there are definitely costs. To quote Roman, "Middleware!" but I'm not skilled enough to know if that's a relevant comment.

Comment: I've been living by that slogan "Middleware!" , changed the way I write javascript. Interesting idea to use it to configure multiple apps in directories.